# Upgrade to ros-melodic from ros-kinetic

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04, so i'm planning to upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04. Since i know ros-kinetic is not supported on Ubuntu 18.04. So i'm ready to use ros-melodic. But the question is before upgrading to Ubuntu to 18.04 should i uninstall ros-kinetic first?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343402/upgrade-to-ros-melodic-from-ros-kinetic/) by [rosbie0602](https://answers.ros.org/users/51514/rosbie0602/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I actually recently did this transition myself for my home machines.

If you attempt to go through the Ubuntu upgrade system to change to 18.04, you'll get about 80% done and it'll complain about some really esoteric things that couldn't be changed. I don't remember off hand. After a few hours of investigating, I figured it may be ROS because that's the only non-vanilla thing I have on my machine.

After uninstalling ROS, and attempting again, it worked fine. So yes, I would recommend fully uninstalling ROS Kinetic. After the upgrade, go through a fresh Melodic install.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did this recently, but I did not upgrade via the Ubuntu upgrade, I copied my important data to another hard-drive and reformatted my disk with fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.
I think in your case it is better to completely remove all existing ros-kinetic packages , then upgrade to 18.04 and finally reinstall ros-melodic packages.

---

Originally posted by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) with karma: 819 on 2020-02-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosbie0602](https://answers.ros.org/users/51514/rosbie0602/) on 2020-02-06**:
The reason I don't want to fresh install ubuntu 18.04 is that I have dual booted my laptop and i don't trust Ubuntu installation process.

**Comment by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) on 2020-02-06**:
yes, I did so because I needed to reformat my computer anyway,otherwise I would also follow upgrade process instead of fresh install

**Comment by [Santosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/60740/santosh/) on 2020-10-11**:
Does workspace built in kinetic remain as it is after upgrading to melodic ?